# Translate a JQuery-Javascript call to Coffeescript (Rails 3.1)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I am currently upgrading a Rails application. While I did manage to translate simpler JQuery calls, I got stuck with the more complex JQuery autocomplete.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var data_category = <%= @autocomplete_categories %>;
    $("#entry_category").autocomplete({ 
        source: function(req, responseFn) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
            var a = $.grep( data_category, function(item,index) {
                return matcher.test(item);
            });
            responseFn( a );
        }, 
        minLength: 0, 
        delay: 0, 
        autoFocus: true 
    });
```

Coffescript:

```
  $ ->
    data_category = <%= @autocomplete_category %>;
    $("#entry_category").autocomplete({
```

I don't manage to translate the two functions, please advise on the correct syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ->
  data_category = <%= @autocomplete_categories %>
  $('#entry_category').autocomplete
    source: (req, responseFn) ->
      re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex req.term
      matcher = new RegExp "^#{re}", 'i'
      a = $.grep data_category, (item, index) -> matcher.test item
      responseFn(a)
    minLength: 0
    delay: 0
    autoFocus: true
```

Comment: Close to perfekt. The JQuery is invoked, however, the list is empty. I added alert data_category and this results in undefined. A debug output in _forms.html.erb (a partial) of <%= @autocomplete_categories %> displays the list elements. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I actually don't know Rails, but is that the right name for the list? In your Javascript you have 'autocomplete_categories' but in your coffeescript you have 'autocomplete_category'. Was this working in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, just re-checked, it works in JS and not with your code above. The problem seems to be that the @autocomplete_categories are not assigned or available in this scope. `data_category = <%= @autocomplete_categories %> alert(<%= @autocomplete_categories %>) alert(data_category)` and both alerts display undefined. In the view, a debug of `@autocomplete_categories` displays the list, so the view corresponding view has the data.

Comment: I found out, that one can not access variables from the controller in the coffeescript. There are some workarounds for single variables, with a quick google search I did not find anything for lists. Will try again, in the meantime thank you for the translation of the query!